# How to make right aligned inner element inside a pre tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, responsive-design

I have an issue that should be fixed through the CSS/Query only - HTML change is not possible because HTML is implemented on thousands of the pages on the website.

screenshot (1)

[image]

It works fine if the width is less, but when scrollbar is visible, and I move it to the right to see the code, then "COPY" button also shifted to the left,

creenshot (2)

[image]

I added the copy button using the script and it is working fine with thousands of the pages. Unable to fix the issue.

**HTML:**

```
<pre class="i3-code">
--example code--
</pre>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function cpy(t){var e=t.innerText,n=document.createElement("textarea");n.setAttribute("class","invisible"),n.setAttribute("id","cpytxtbox"),n.textContent=e,document.body.append(n),n.select(),document.execCommand("copy"),document.getElementById("cpytxtbox").outerHTML=""}var $input=$('<div class="copy-btn"><input type="button" value="Copy"/></div>');$input.prependTo($(".i3-code")),$(".copy-btn").click(function(){cpy(this.parentElement)});
  </script>
```

**CSS:**

```
.i3-code {
    background-color: #fefbed;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
.copy-btn {
    text-align: right;
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-right: -8px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
.copy-btn input {
    background: #e1e1e1;
    color: #000;
    border: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 7px;
    transition: background 1s;
}
```

A live test can be done with this URL (on any example code), by resizing the window screen

```
https://www.includehelp.com/python/date-toordinal-method-with-example.aspx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
.copy-btn {
    text-align: right;
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-right: -8px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    position: sticky;
    top: -8px;
    left: -8px;
    right: -8px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

It implements [position: sticky](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp).

Comment: Wow :) Thanks, it's working but should I use "position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */"

Comment: @ted without using "position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */" - its working on my iPhone11 also, so kindly suggest, it should work on all browsers

Comment: @Mike Well yeah, it's always a good idea to add vendor prefixes for CSS3 rules. `position:sticky` has no IE support tho. See: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky
If you want to support all browsers, I suggest finding an alternative to sticky. But now at least you have a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to- 
 fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
  integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" 
  crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
<pre class="float-right position-sticky">
</pre>




  </body>
</html>
```